# Camry 2011 Demister is not working

Tags: electrical, toyota, camry, fuse

When I used to turn Demister on I used to smell like plastic burning smell.
then the Demister stopped working

What could be the reason?
could it be the fuse?
if so where can I find the fuse box in the camry and which one is for the Demister?

Demister is the lines in the back windshield that stops fog in the back windshield

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! For those of us here in the States, can you explain what the demister actually does? I'm making sure I understand what's going on.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 i have edited the question

Comment: See, that's why I asked! Here in the States we call it a "defroster", though I hear you don't get much in the way of frost in Australia, so can understand why you don't call it that, lol!

Comment: I can find fuse layouts for left-hand drive cars, but finding them for right-hand drive cars here in the States is another story. There are going to be two fuse panels: one under the dash on the driver's side and one under the bonnet in the engine compartment. Each cover should have a map of the fuses which are in each. Check both to see if you can find the fuse. Really, if you smelled burnt plastic, I'm doubting it's a fuse, but something more substantial.

Comment: Does the warning light still come on in the switch? Have you checked the connections to the rear window? If they are loose that can cause local heating and burning. Have you checked for any damage to the wires leading to the window? Otherwise relay and fuse(s).